# does getWritableDatabase() affect transactions

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

As i understand it, calling `SqliteOpendHelper.getWritableDatabase()` always returns the same instance of `SQLiteDatabase`. So would a transaction associated with it also remain unaffected?

Assume a single threaded environment and i use a singleton SQLiteOpenHelper instance. Suppose i have a long transaction :

- I call `SQLiteDatabase.beginTransaction()` once.
- DAO1 constructor calls `SqliteOpendHelper.getWritableDatabase()`.
- DAO1 method performs a CRUD operation on it.
- DAO2 constructor calls `SqliteOpendHelper.getWritableDatabase()`.
- DAO2 method performs a CRUD operation on it.
- ...on and on
- I call `SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction()` once.

**Do all the DAO operations get executed within that single transaction?** I could not figure out from the [source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.java#getDatabaseLocked) if multiple calls to `getWritableDatabase()` effects transactions in some way.

Comment: I have tried the same with singleton approach and got to see that it doesn't work that way if you are using content provider instead of DAO. Even if singleton instance is maintained for SQLiteOpenHelper and we get the same SQLiteDatabse instance across contentprovider call, it will not work as we expect. transaction has to be closed within each contentprovider call.

Comment: @Aun that's interesting. YOu mean the transaction does not get committed if you don't end it in the `ContentProvider`?

Comment: I have make a call API to commit transaction. It doesn't work that way.
All further CRUD call will get blocked..

Comment: Is it not better to start the transaction after you get the handle? because getWritableDatabase can trigger onCreate/onUpgrade, then if there's a problem with your CRUD the whole init will also be rolled back which is likely not desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; `getWritableDatabase()` always returns the same connection object (unless it was closed previously), and a single database connection always uses a single transaction, so all operations done through it are in the same transaction.

Please note that `SQLiteDatabase` supports nesting of the transaction calls, so it is safe for the lower-level CRUD operations to do their own transactions, regardless from where they are called.